# NodeMCU UDP DNS request format

Tags: lua, dns, packet, nodemcu

I am looking at [this example](https://github.com/reischle/CaptiveIntraweb/tree/dev) of a captive portal built on a NodeMCU platform, and I am trying to understand how DNS requests work. (The relevant file is `dns-liar.lua`) I have more or less decoded what the response is, but have no idea what each part of it does, and I can't find any online resources that show a similar packet structure.

IP of NodeMCU:

```
a.b.c.d
```

Request:

```
|A|B| ... |(13th byte) \0 terminated string (str)| ...
```

Response: (bytes separated by "|")

```
|A|B|x80|x00|x00|x01|x00|x01|x00|x00|x00|x00|str|x00|x01|x00|x01|xC0|x0C|x00|x01|x00|x01|x00|x00|x03|x00|x00|x04|a|b|c|d|
```

I gather that the `str` is likely the domain to search for, and `abcd` is simply the NodeMCU responding to every request with its own IP address, but I'm not sure what any of the other bytes are doing.

Comment: Are you asking about the DNS message format? If so (I have my doubts) then I suggest http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_DNSMessageHeaderandQuestionSectionFormat.htm or https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd197470(v=ws.10).aspx - apart from RFC2136 of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whew!  It's always tricky when folks decide to preformat nearly a whole packet ahead of time, especially when it spans several subsections of the RFC.

Anyhow, I went ahead and forked [CaptiveIntraweb](https://github.com/reischle/CaptiveIntraweb) and commented up the DNS code.  I've also [submitted a PR](https://github.com/reischle/CaptiveIntraweb/pull/7) with my changes so it hopefully gets pulled upstream in a future release.  You can read the whole thing there (it goes over every DNS field in detail), but here are the highlights of what the author is doing:

1. The first two bytes are a copy of the ID field parsed from the request
2. The next 10 bytes are a premade header including the type of packet and so on (..._str1).
3. The next X bytes are a copy of the NAME requested from the request
4. The next 4 bytes are the rest of the question data (type/class) and the next 14 bytes are the compressed NAME, and the type/class/ttl/length of the response (..._str2).
5. Finally, the last four bytes are the IP of the node.

Comment: Very detailed comments, they were very informative!